Word for somebody who is only friendly to people who are in their group of people
I do not mean a bigot or a racist. I mean, for example: a person who has a group of friends, and these people have other friends, but this person is very standoffish and even rude to these other people's friends. Or another example: a step-father who is only open and friendly to his own biological children, but doesn't accept his step-children no matter what they do.

selectively social.....

Shy? I mean it probably depends on the reason for their behaviour.

It's an  elitist or snob carried to an extreme.

inward-looking (not willing to consider ideas that are different from your own, or to work together with people from different groups or places) or parochial (showing interest only in a narrow range of matters) ?

They belong to a clique.
A small group of people who spend their time together and do not welcome other people into that group
Anyone in the group can be described as cliquey.

"Cliquish" could also be an option for the adjective, and is perhaps more often applied to the individuals as opposed to the group

yes, good point
